# mouting NFSv4 filesystem returning "Permissions denied"

Tags: redhat, nfs4

I am using Red Hat for NFS with Kerberos client:

```
[root@perf-c238 ~]# cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.18-92.el5 (brewbuilder@ls20-bc2-13.build.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-41)) #1 SMP Tue Apr 29 13:16:15 EDT 2008
```

NFS with Kerberos server is :

```
[root@krbserver ~]# cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.9.6-200.fc18.i686 (mockbuild@bkernel01.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Jun 13 19:29:40 UTC 2013
```

While doing mount, I am getting "Permission denied" error, and am seeing these messages in `/var/log/messages` on the client:

```
Apr  6 09:03:03 perf-c238 rpc.gssd[29050]: WARNING: Failed to obtain machine credentials for connection to server krbserver.test.com
```

Can someone please help in debugging this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your kerberos setup on the would appear to be incorrect. (unless you edited your output to say krbserver.test.com)

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Configuring_Identity_Management/nfs.html

If `kinit` does not work also, look in `/var/log/krb5.log`. Make sure `/etc/krb5.conf` is set up to reflect your setup.